spider_closed signal not handled when interrupted
I've got a scrapy spider that I'm running in a different fashion than usual because I sometimes want to run the spider again after it finishes.  Here's my code:
class LinkExtractorSpider(scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider):
    name = 'LinkExtractor'

    rules = [
        scrapy.spiders.Rule(
            scrapy.linkextractors.LinkExtractor(),
            callback='produce_url',
            follow=True,
        )
    ]

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url=self.settings['START_URL'])

    def produce_url(self, response):
        yield {'url': response.url}


class Pipeline:
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        logging.info(f'Check: {item}')

    def spider_closed(self, spider, reason):
        logging.info(f'Spider closed because: {reason}')
        logging.info('Cleanup code would go here')

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        pipeline = Pipeline()
        crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_closed, signal=scrapy.signals.spider_closed)
        return pipeline


class Crawler:
    def __init__(self):
        os.environ['SCRAPY_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'
        scrapy.utils.log.configure_logging()
        self.settings = scrapy.utils.project.get_project_settings()
        self.runner = scrapy.crawler.CrawlerRunner(self.settings)

    def should_run_again(self):
        return False

    def callback(self, results):
        logging.info("Maybe I want to run again, maybe not")
        if self.should_run_again():
            self.runner.crawl(LinkExtractorSpider).addCallback(self.callback)
        else:
            twisted.internet.reactor.stop()

    def run(self, start_url):
        if not start_url.startswith('http'):
            start_url = 'https://' + start_url
        self.settings.set('START_URL', start_url)
        self.runner.crawl(LinkExtractorSpider).addCallback(self.callback)
        twisted.internet.reactor.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Crawler().run('some_website.com')

This works just fine and I see the logging messages from both my callback and my pipeline's spider_closed method.  However, when I interrupt the script with a Ctrl-C, it exits cleanly but neither of those messages appear.
Here's my settings.py:
import logging

ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    "spider.Pipeline": 100,
}

LOG_LEVEL = logging.INFO
LOG_FORMAT = "%(name)s: [%(levelname)s] %(message)s"
LOG_STDOUT = True

ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT = 10
RETRY_ENABLED = False
DEPTH_LIMIT = 2

Here are the logs:
scrapy.addons: [INFO] Enabled addons:
[]
py.warnings: [WARNING] /Users/daniel/environments/poisonedparadox/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scrapy/utils/request.py:254: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: '2.6' is a deprecated value for the 'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION' setting.

It is also the default value. In other words, it is normal to get this warning if you have not defined a value for the 'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION' setting. This is so for backward compatibility reasons, but it will change in a future version of Scrapy.

See the documentation of the 'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION' setting for information on how to handle this deprecation.
  return cls(crawler)

scrapy.extensions.telnet: [INFO] Telnet Password: aaaaaaaaa
scrapy.middleware: [INFO] Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
scrapy.crawler: [INFO] Overridden settings:
{'DEPTH_LIMIT': 2,
 'DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT': 10,
 'LOG_FORMAT': '%(name)s: [%(levelname)s] %(message)s',
 'LOG_LEVEL': 20,
 'LOG_STDOUT': True,
 'RETRY_ENABLED': False}
scrapy.middleware: [INFO] Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
scrapy.middleware: [INFO] Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
scrapy.middleware: [INFO] Enabled item pipelines:
['spider.Pipeline']
scrapy.core.engine: [INFO] Spider opened
scrapy.extensions.logstats: [INFO] Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
scrapy.extensions.telnet: [INFO] Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
root: [INFO] Check: {'url': 'https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/privacy/'}
root: [INFO] Check: {'url': 'https://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi'}
root: [INFO] Check: {'url': 'https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/terms/'}
root: [INFO] Check: {'url': 'https://www.google.com/preferences?hl=en'}
root: [INFO] Check: {'url': 'https://www.google.com/advanced_search?hl=en&authuser=0'}
root: [INFO] Check: {'url': 'https://smallbusiness.withgoogle.com/?subid=us-en-et-g-awa-a-g_hpbfoot1_1!o2&utm_source=google&utm_medium=ep&utm_campaign=google_hpbfooter&utm_content=google_hpbfooter&gmbsrc=us-en_US-et-gs-z-gmb-s-z-u~sb-g4sb_srvcs-u'}
root: [INFO] Check: {'url': 'https://www.google.com/maps?hl=en&tab=wl'}
root: [INFO] Check: {'url': 'https://ads.google.com/intl/en/home/'}
root: [INFO] Check: {'url': 'https://about.google/'}
root: [INFO] Check: {'url': 'https://www.google.com/history/optout?hl=en'}
root: [INFO] Check: {'url': 'https://news.google.com/home?tab=wn&hl=en-US&gl=US&ceid=US:en'}
root: [INFO] Check: {'url': 'https://about.google/products/?tab=wh'}
root: [INFO] Check: {'url': 'https://www.youtube.com/?tab=w1'}
root: [INFO] Check: {'url': 'https://accounts.google.com/v3/signin/identifier?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&ec=GAZAAQ&hl=en&ifkv=AcMMx-d2GgD-YTcHQJRQ98PqHE-zo-q3UYpsuA9APS1CY6G3mBsmxU_kgZuengZK0fVjecGRTCpIug&passive=true&flowName=WebLiteSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin&dsh=S-1389799524%3A1730486180270110'}
root: [INFO] Check: {'url': 'https://www.google.com/advanced_image_search?hl=en&authuser=0'}
root: [INFO] Check: {'url': 'https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+vote+in+the+us&hl=en&gl=us&stick=H4sIAAAAAAAAAHvE6Mgt8PLHPWEpi0lrTl5jNOISdM1JTS7JzM_zyC8PyQ_LL0kVkuXigAkKCUrxc_Hqp-sbGuaWFeRmZVTl8CxiFc3IL1coyVcoA6pWyMxTKMlIVSgtBgCjAj5eXAAAAA&utm_source=discover&utm_medium=promo&utm_campaign=13'}
root: [INFO] Check: {'url': 'https://policies.google.com/privacy?hl=en&gl=us'}
root: [INFO] Check: {'url': 'https://policies.google.com/terms'}
^Cscrapy.core.downloader.handlers.http11: [WARNING] Got data loss in https://play.google.com/store/games?hl=en&tab=w8. If you want to process broken responses set the setting DOWNLOAD_FAIL_ON_DATALOSS = False -- This message won't be shown in further requests
scrapy.core.downloader.handlers.http11: [WARNING] Got data loss in https://support.google.com/. If you want to process broken responses set the setting DOWNLOAD_FAIL_ON_DATALOSS = False -- This message won't be shown in further requests

The last few messages about data loss occur when I hit Ctrl-C.

Can You please include fragments from log output of this?
Especitally interested in first entries (from scrapy version.., all log entries to first request including l.e. with "Enabled extensions, pipelines, middlewares etc.)
and ending entries after first Ctrl+C (including "dump stats" entry - if exists of course)


However, when I interrupt the script with a Ctrl-C, it exits cleanly
but neither of those messages appear.

Processing of CTRL+C implemented in scrapy.utils.ossignal.install_shutdown_handlers (source code)
This function used in scrapy.crawler.CrawlerProcess._signal_shutdown (source code) 
scrapy.crawler.CrawlerProcess class is descendant of  scrapy.crawler.CrawlerRunner
Unfortunately scrapy.crawler.CrawlerRunner class used in Your code - doesn't have installed handlers of CTRL+C as result of this - application didn't react to CTRL+C as initially expected.
Update

I've got a scrapy spider that I'm running in a different fashion than
usual because I sometimes want to run the spider again after it
finishes

As possible alternative I'd also recommend approach from Support starting spiders from spiders #1226 (gh repo comment)
It's launch code will look something like (transfer CrawlerProcess object to spider

...
if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(LinkExtractorSpider, proc=process)
    process.start()

and on close_spider.. something like this (should work.. theoretically - by this moment that calls tested only from spider methods).

class Pipeline:
....

    def spider_closed(self, spider, reason):
        logging.info(f'Spider closed because: {reason}')
        logging.info('Cleanup code would go here')
        if NEED_TO_LAUNCH_AGAIN:
            spider.proc.crawl(LinkExtractorSpider, proc=spider.proc)


Switching to a CrawlerProcess didn't change anything.

scrapy.crawler.CrawlerProcess._signal_shutdown I mentioned above called inside CrawlerProcess.start() method that I assume didn't called (my guess as I didn't see Your updated code with CrawlerProcess.

Do I need to call _signal_shutdown?

It CrawlerProcess.start() was called as suggested by scrapy docs - then _signal_shutdown is called too
